# When adding any SCNNode, sometime its taking position on the air but not exact on surface. How to set minimum depth

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, scnnode

When adding any SCNNode, sometimes it took position on the air but not exactly on the surface. How to set the minimum depth of the same? You can check the image I've attached.
[image]

How to detect the position of the exact surface from the distance and drop the node at that position.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community When I am adding any SCNNode to the ARSCNView, sometimes that node taking a position on the air as you can see in the above-attached image with a green bg node and with the value of 121.